# How to resize an SVG using media queries?

Tags: html, css, svg

I know you can use the viewBox attribute to resize it normally but how do I specify or select that attribute in CSS?

my current code is:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    svg {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the SVG document/animation in the centre of the page and make it be 100% of the viewport width when the viewport is below 767 pixels. 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with `width: 100vw;`? Can you please provide a working and minimal example ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a wrapper around the svg with `text-align: center` to center the svg. Use `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {}` for the media query.

The HTML code:

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
  <svg>
    <rect/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

The CSS Code:

```css
.svg-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

svg,
rect {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  svg,
  rect {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

height: 100%;
width: 100%: 
was all that was required.